# Append strings to a file based on a particular string position

Tags: java

I have cucumber feature file(`test.feature`)

```
Feature: annotation  
Background: 
User navigates to Facebook 
Given I am on Facebook login page 

Scenario: When I enter username as "TOM" 
And I enter password as "JERRY" 
Then Login should fail 

Scenario: When I enter username as "TOM" 
And I enter password as "JERRY" 
Then Login should fail 
But Relogin option should be available
```

And  need to add tags (incrementing order) via java code .like

```
 Feature: annotation  
Background: 
User navigates to Facebook 
Given I am on Facebook login page 
@tag1
Scenario: When I enter username as "TOM" 
And I enter password as "JERRY" 
Then Login should fail 
@tag2
Scenario: When I enter username as "TOM" 
And I enter password as "JERRY" 
Then Login should fail 
But Relogin option should be available
```

tags will be added in the incrementing order.Is there any possible way to add @tag above the string 'Scenario:'

How can it is possible with java code.Any solutions.

I tried with following code.But not able to procced to append to the position above the string 'Scenario:'

```
 int count =0;

           BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.feature"));
           FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("test.feature");
           while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { 
                if (line.trim().startsWith("Scenario")) {
                    count++;
                    writer.write("tag"+count);

                }
           }
           //Final Dump data here 
            writer.close();        
           bufferedReader.close();
```

Comment: The following logic is easier I think, `read file1` `output to file2` `delete file1` `rename file2 to file1`

Comment: yes thats correct!.....But what am facing right now is i am not able to append the tag like(@tag1) above above each scenario

Comment: why are you doing `writer.close();`  where are you writing the rest of the content?

Comment: that was a mistake...i changed

Comment: any logic to add string "@tag1" above "Scenario:" string

Comment: did my answer resolve your issue?  if so please accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you want to print the line as well **edit** added newlines

```
if (line.trim().startsWith("Scenario")) {
    count++;
    writer.write("@tag"+count);
    writer.write ("\n"); 
}
writer.write (line);
writer.write ("\n");
```