# Edit or modify the existing file using java

Tags: java, file

am trying to modify the existing below file.

```
User navigates to Facebook 
Given I am on Facebook login page 

Scenario: enter username as "TOM" 
And I enter password as "JERRY" 


Feature: annotation  
Background: 
User navigates to Facebook 
Given I am on Facebook login page 

But Relogin option should be available
```

I tried with below code and file contents become cleared!

```
public void addTags(File file) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {               
            fw = new FileWriter(file);

            fw.write(line);
            fw.write("\n");
            fw.close();
        }       
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
```

Please correct me..whats wrong with my code.

Comment: Where do you initialize your BufferedWriter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append strings to a file based on a particular string position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42129708/append-strings-to-a-file-based-on-a-particular-string-position)

Comment: I don't see the difference with the other question you ask 5hours ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to read the file before you can write it.

So first read the file line by line into an ArrayList.

There's an easy way using `Files.readAllLines(yourPath)`.

After that, just iterate over the list and write into the file as you already did. Just don't forget to close the `BufferedWriter`.

I'd suggest to initialize it inside a try-block:

try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(yourFile))){
    //write yourFile
}

That way you don't have to handle the closing of the writers.

Like that:

```
private static void readWrite(Path filePath) throws IOException {
    List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(filePath);
    int count = 0;
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath.toFile()))) {
      for (String line : allLines) {
        if (line.trim().contains("Scenario")) {
          count++;
          bw.write("@tag" + count);
          bw.write("\n");
        }
        bw.write(line);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is in this line of code

```
fw = new FileWriter(file);
```

Firstly, you are initializing fw in while loop. It gets reinitialized every time the loop gets executed.
Secondly, you cannot read and write into same file. You have to create new file, copy from old one, insert new data, copy rest and so on. If you want new file behave as edited old file, you will have to delete old file and rename new one. 
Also your bw is not initialized;

Fixed code should look like this:

```
public void addTags(File file) throws IOException {
    File tmp = new File(temp.txt);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmp));
    String line;
    int count = 0;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {           
        if (line.trim().contains("Scenario")) {
            count++;
            bw.write("@tag" + count);
            bw.write("\n");
        }
        fw.writeLine(line);
    }
    fw.close();
    bufferedReader.close();
    String newName = file.getName();
    Files.delete(file);
    tmp.renameTo(newName);
}
```